# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT at cross_validation_metrics_summary

Tags: apache-spark, h2o, sparkling-water

I'm using the `H2ODRF` and `H2OGridSearch` models to create a random forest pipeline with random discrete grid search hyper-parameter optimization. However, when I set nfolds to any number greater than 1 and call `fit()`, I get an error. My code looks like this:

```
val drf =  new H2ODRF()
    .setFeaturesCols(featuresCols)
    .setLabelCol(labelCol)
    .setColumnsToCategorical(categoricalCols)
    .setSplitRatio(splitRatio)
    .setNfolds(4)

val nps = Map(
        "ntrees" -> Array(10, 50).map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]))

val search = new H2OGridSearch()
    .setHyperParameters(hyperParams)
    .setAlgo(drf)

val model = search.fit(data) // data is a Spark DataFrame
```

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 608096 path $.cross_validation_metrics_summary[0].data[0][0]
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
  at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.backend.utils.RestCommunication$class.ai$h2o$sparkling$backend$utils$RestCommunication$$deserialize(RestCommunication.scala:164)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.backend.utils.RestCommunication$$anonfun$request$1.apply(RestCommunication.scala:147)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.backend.utils.RestCommunication$$anonfun$request$1.apply(RestCommunication.scala:145)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.utils.ScalaUtils$.withResource(ScalaUtils.scala:28)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.backend.utils.RestCommunication$class.request(RestCommunication.scala:145)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.ml.algos.H2OGridSearch.request(H2OGridSearch.scala:46)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.backend.utils.RestCommunication$class.query(RestCommunication.scala:54)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.ml.algos.H2OGridSearch.query(H2OGridSearch.scala:46)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.ml.algos.H2OGridSearch.getGridModels(H2OGridSearch.scala:129)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.ml.algos.H2OGridSearch.fit(H2OGridSearch.scala:163)
  at ai.h2o.sparkling.ml.algos.H2OGridSearch.fit(H2OGridSearch.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:153)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$fit$2.apply(Pipeline.scala:149)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
  at scala.collection.IterableViewLike$Transformed$class.foreach(IterableViewLike.scala:44)
  at scala.collection.SeqViewLike$AbstractTransformed.foreach(SeqViewLike.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:149)
  ... 59 elided
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 608096 path $.cross_validation_metrics_summary[0].data[0][0]
  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
  at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
  ... 90 more
```

The error seems to be caused by a `cross_validation_metrics_summary` field which is only returned when Nfolds is greater than 1. Is there a work around to this problem?

**Edit**:
I'm using the [Prostate Data](https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/examples/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv) and using Spark version `2.4.4`, Scala Version `2.11.12`, and using the following sparkling water version `ai.h2o:sparkling-water-package_2.11:3.30.0.4-1-2.4`.

**Edit**:
After scouring through the Sparkling Water source code, it's starting to look like the issue is with a misconfigured schema in `GridSchemaV99`. Is there a setting/configuration I am supposed to update that looks for a different schema?

Comment: Please add to your question your spark version, the version of your library and an example of your data which also causes the error.

Comment: I have added them:

" I'm using the Prostate Data and using Spark version 2.4.4, Scala Version 2.11.12, and using the following sparkling water version ai.h2o:sparkling-water-package_2.11:3.30.0.4-1-2.4."